# ARM pc register is not always the address of the current instruction plus 4 (Thumb state)

Tags: assembly, arm

According to the ARM IC.

In Thumb state:

- For B, BL, CBNZ, and CBZ instructions, the value of the PC is the address of the current instruction plus 4 bytes.
- For all other instructions that use labels, the value of the PC is the address of the current instruction plus 4 bytes.

When debugging a program, I found pc is not always is the address of the current instruction plus 4 bytes,e.g., the following instruction(2).
Could someone give some explanations? thanks.

```
0x2a003118  ldr r3, [pc, #120]  ; (0x2a003194 <main()+684>)   <---(1)
0x2a00311a  ldr r3, [r4, r3] 
0x2a00311c  mov r0, r3 
0x2a00311e  ldr r3, [pc, #136]  ; (0x2a0031a8 <main()+704>)   <---(2)
0x2a003120  add r3, pc                                        <---(3)
0x2a003122  mov r1, r3 
0x2a003124  bl 0x2a00338c
0x2a003128  mov r3, r0 
0x2a00312a  mov r0, r3 
0x2a00312c  ldr r3, [pc, #108]  ; (0x2a00319c <main()+692>)   <---(4)
```

============================================================

```
(1).ldr r3, [pc, #120] ; (0x2a003194 <main()+684>)
    p/x $pc+4+120 
    $1 = 0x2a003194
   ; $pc+4 ,Correct

(2).ldr r3, [pc, #136] ; (0x2a0031a8 <main()+704>) 
    p/x $pc+4+136 
    $2 = 0x2a0031aa
   ; Wrong! it should be 0x2a0031a8($pc+2) instead of 0x2a0031aa($pc+4).

(3).add r3, pc
    p/x $r3+$pc+4  
    $3 = 0x2a025c04
   ; $pc+4 ,Correct

(4).ldr r3, [pc, #108]  ; (0x2a00319c <main()+692>)
    p/x $pc+4+108 
    $4 = 0x2a00319c
   ; $pc+4 ,Correct
```

Comment: You wrote +4 both times; did you mean +2 bytes for one of them?   Or did you really mean to write the same thing for the two different cases?

Comment: I forget what Thumb2 mode does with 4-byte instructions; probably it's PC + 2 insns rather than fixed at 4 bytes.  Your `bl` is 4 bytes long (I think it might actually be a pseudo-instruction for 2 Thumb-mode instructions that combine to give the displacement.)

Answer (score 1):

In ARM DDI 0487B.a

> T32 restrictions on the use of the PC, and use of 0b1111 as a register
>   specifier The use of 0b1111 as a register specifier is not normally
>   permitted in T32 instructions. When a value of 0b1111 is permitted, a
>   variety of meanings is possible. For register reads, these meanings
>   include:
>
> - Read the PC value, that is, the address of the current instruction + 4. The base register of the table branch instructions TBB and TBH can be the PC. This means branch tables can be placed in memory
>     immediately after the instruction.
>
> *Note - ARM deprecates use of the PC as the base register in the STC instruction.*
>
> - Read the word-aligned PC value, that is, the address of the current instruction + 4, **with bits[1:0] forced to zero.** The base register
>     of LDC, LDR, LDRB, LDRD (pre-indexed, no writeback), LDRH, LDRSB, and
>     LDRSH instructions can be the word-aligned PC. This provides
>     PC-relative data addressing. In addition, some encodings of the ADD
>     and SUB instructions permit their source registers to be 0b1111 for
>     the same purpose.

You should look for something similar in your reference.